# In Datepicker, why is default date NOT highlighted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI's DatePickerand the `defaultDate` is set to `04/27/2017`, yet when I open the DatePicker, the 24th (today's date) is highlighted but the 27th is not. Please see the screengrab below datepicker code for an example of the problem. How can I fix this?

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: dateToday,
  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
  defaultDate: 04/27/17,
  beforeShow:function(textbox, instance) {
    $('#dob-dialog').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
  }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the `defaultDate` property value as a Date object or a string which can be coerced to a date. Try this:

```
defaultDate: '04/27/17',
```

```js
var dateToday = new Date();

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: dateToday,
  dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
  defaultDate: '04/27/17',
  beforeShow: function(textbox, instance) {
    $('#dob-dialog').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```